# Assign optional functions to Javascript class

Tags: javascript

I am creating a simple Javascript class that i essentially want to have 'event listeners' on certain areas of a `start()` process. I have a class in one file and create an instance of that class in another file. I then want to attach a listener on part of the class and IF the user provides a function to the class listener, then execute it.

myClass.js

```
export class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.beforeStart = null;
    this.started = null;
    this.beforeEnd = null;
    this.ended = null;
  }

  async start() {
    if (typeof this.beforeStart == 'function') await this.beforeStart();

    // .....start logic here..
    console.log('start logic here..');

    if (typeof this.started == 'function') await this.started();
  }

  async end() {
    if (typeof this.beforeEnd == 'function') await this.beforeEnd();

    // .....end logic here..
    console.log('end logic here..');

    if (typeof this.ended == 'function') await this.ended();
  }
  
}
```

main.js

```
const nClass = new MyClass();
nClass.beforeStart = () => {
  console.log('await beforeStart work here');
};
nClass.started = () => {
  console.log('await started work here');
};
nClass.beforeEnded = () => {
  console.log('await beforeEnded work here');
};
nClass.ended = () => {
  console.log('await ended work here');
};
nClass.start();
nClass.end();
```

Im looking to be able to have the listeners be awaited so the user can perform various task within the 'listener' hooks.

Comment: `this.ended == 'function'` is in no way shape or form doing any sort of `typeof` comparison.  You are comparing a varible against a string of function.  If you want to do a type of comparison, you have to actually do `typeof this.ended` before the comparison

Comment: That was a typo on my part. I've updated the question. How do i await the 'listeners' so they return in order? Right now they just return in random order.

Comment: Well, my next comment is that `await nClass.beforeStart = () => {};` looks wrong.  You are awaiting on a variable assignment which doesn't make sense.  And the arrow function you assign to the variable is not asynchronous, so later when you try to await on it's invocation, that also doesn't make sense

Comment: If i try to do `await nClass.beforeStart = () => {}` i get error ';' expected.

Comment: Why do you need an await there at all?  Nothing about that is asynchronous.

Comment: Thats what im trying to achieve...How can i make these async?

Comment: You already **are** `await`ing your event listeners when calling them. What do you think does not work?

Comment: Notice you will need to `await nClass.start()` before calling `nClass.end()` though

Comment: All your method declarations have to include `async`, and all your async functions have to `await` whatever asynchronous task they are performing. [Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L9bqy2ct/) of your class in working order.

Answer (score 1):

Answer submitted by @lawrence-witt

This solution works perfectly for me.

```
 const halt = msg => {
    return new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(msg);
      res();
    }, 1000)
  });
};

class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.beforeStart = null;
    this.started = null;
    this.beforeEnd = null;
    this.ended = null;
  }

  async start() {
    if (typeof this.beforeStart == 'function') await this.beforeStart();

    // .....start logic here..
    console.log('executing start logic');

    if (typeof this.started == 'function') await this.started();
  }

  async end() {
    if (typeof this.beforeEnd == 'function') await this.beforeEnd();

    // .....end logic here..
    console.log('executing end logic');

    if (typeof this.ended == 'function') await this.ended();
  }
};

const nClass = new MyClass();
nClass.beforeStart = async () => {
    await halt('beforeStart complete');
};
nClass.started = async () => {
    await halt('started complete');
};
nClass.beforeEnd = async () => {
    await halt('beforeEnd complete');
};
nClass.ended = async () => {
    await halt('ended complete');
};

const run = async () => {
    await nClass.start();
  await nClass.end();
};

run();
```